# Ruby Rails testing removes data when JS is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

When I have a test case written like this:

```
it "creates a slot" do
  expect(p = FactoryGirl.create(:position)).to be_valid()
  expect(e = FactoryGirl.create(:experience)).to be_valid()
  visit new_slot_path
  expect(page).to have_content("New Slot")
  fill_in "slot_name", :with => "Slot test"
  select p.position, from: "slot_position_id"
  click_link "Add Education Experience"
  select e.experience, from: "slot_slots_experiences_attributes_experience_id"
  click_button "Create Slot"
end
```

It cannot find the experience to add. How ever the exact same test written like this, the drop down for experience exists, but the other drop downs for position go missing.

```
it "creates a slot", :js => true do
      expect(p = FactoryGirl.create(:position)).to be_valid()
      expect(e = FactoryGirl.create(:experience)).to be_valid()
      visit new_slot_path
      expect(page).to have_content("New Slot")
      fill_in "slot_name", :with => "Slot test"
      select p.position, from: "slot_position_id"
      click_link "Add Education Experience"
      select e.experience, from: "slot_slots_experiences_attributes_experience_id"
      click_button "Create Slot"
    end
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know where to start. You shouldn't be validating your factories! Move this code to `before` block. If you want to make use factory creates the object before test use `create!` instead of `create` (former will create the object first time you use associated variable)

Comment: Also I hope you realise you assign both position and experience to variable `p`. Maybe using properly names variables could help you here (like `position` and `experience`)

Comment: The same varaible was just a typo on my side when posting on the site here.